# How to user web service with help of soap method

Tags: iphone, web-services, ios4

Hi i am new in iphone development. i have task to develop the application to get the web service.

I try to find source but i found some source but it cant give me any output.

So please help me and provide any example if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for most network needs. However, it does not directly support SOAP. I don't know of any iPhone library that does. If you can address your web service without the overhead of SOAP then ASIHTTPRequest will make it simple for XML or JSON. If you really have no choice but to use SOAP then the following may help

http://devmylife.com/?p=111